# npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY not getting suppressed

Tags: angular, angular7

I am working on angular 7 application and get optional dependency warning while doing npm install. What I gather is that the following command should be used to not get those warnings but still seem to get. I have ensured that pacakge-lock and shrinkwrap files dont exist in the folder.

```
npm install --no-optional --no-shrinkwrap --no-package-lock
```

Warning messages

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> The `--no-optional` argument will prevent optional dependencies from being installed.

It says nothing about not warning you, which would not be intuitive anyway. The message tells you it is skipping the optional dependency, which is exactly right and appropriate.

The other two parameters you specified only relate to forcing the use of package.json instead of the lock file.

Unfortunately, [setting the loglevel](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#loglevel) isn't going to help you either because it can only suppress all warnings, or show all of them.